# php arrays, foreach key is skipping a value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

a php noob here. Just started a month ago. I'm currently using a `foreach key=> value` to iterate through two arrays simultaneously. However, after some debugging I've found that in my code, the key skips the number `1`? i.e the key value goes `[0 2 3 4 ...]`. 
Here's my code:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['array'] as $key=>$value)
{

echo $key;

//set up mysql connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
//select database
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

$value= mysql_real_escape_string($value);
$query = "SELECT Hours
FROM Table
WHERE Activity = '$value';";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo $row['Hours'];
    echo '<br>';


    }
?>
```

The odd thing is I've called the same script earlier but on a different array and the key value doesn't skip, so this is baffling me. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Here are the contents of my array as asked for.

```
//key array
 array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [2]=> string(4) "abcd" }
//value array
 array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "8" }
```

I see the issue here, as the key and value iterations don't match. I am currently using a jQuery clone function to clone the arrays dynamically, could this be the issue?

**UPDATE**: Okay I've solved this issue, it was due to the jQuery cloning script I was using. I had adapted an existing script for my own work, and missed a few crucial id numberings in there. Thanks for the var_dump tip guys, it set me on the right path.

Comment: are you sure the key is in the post array?  Add this before your `foreach`: `var_dump($_POST['array']);` and make sure the contents of the array are what you expect.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `var_dump($_POST['array'])` ?

Comment: what do you mean by skipping? are you not getting the result? try to `echo $query;` and check

Comment: thanks guys, managed to solve it. working fine now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
function FixArrayKeys(&$array) {
    $max = key(end($array));
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        if(!isset($array[$i])) {
            $array[$i] = '';
        }
    }
}

FixArrayKeys($_POST['array']);
```

It should do the trick!

*This function should be called before you run foreach.*